# Laptop keeps dropping connection and coming back to same screen

Tags: networking, connection

I have this problem, I'm trying to connect with a Windows XP laptop (Dell Inspiron) to the internet. We recently got AT&T U-Verse and all of our other computers can connect fine, it's only this one that has the problem. Now, what keeps happening is that I will go to the network selection screen and click on my home network. I enter the passkey correctly, and the laptop attempts to connect. It shows the message that it is trying to connect, and shows it for a long time (about 3-5 mins). It then simply drops the message and reverts to the network selection screen. No error message or anything.

Breakdown:

Dell Inspiron laptop with Windows XP

Uses Linksys 802.11g network card

U-Verse uses Motorola NVG510

Problem: Just keeps reverting back to network selection screen while trying to connect.

Note: I had to actually faced the same old problem back when we switched to a different router and network, I had to go fix something in the registry, but I forgot, it was so long ago I had to do that.

Narwhal.

Answer (score 1):

Is the dell laptop on Windows XP SP2? XP SP2 does not have support for WPA2, you need to apply [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1974) patch to get WPA2 support in winodws XP

Comment: That. If I knew it I could save a day of work. I didn't actually get the patch, instead I ended up installing SP3 on every laptop lying around in the office.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this situation before, but not sure if it applied to you.

It happen when I upgrade to latest 812.11N wireless router. We setup it to use N and G, all other device working correctly except for this one laptop. Most of the time it can't see the SSID, so can't connect to it.

Back then we just set the wireless router to use G only (no N). Then only it able to use wifi.

Now we just have extra 812.11G only wireless router to handle this kind of problem. We don't have much anyway, 1 or 2 only.